# Calculate Year Distance Pivot SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
InspectYear     Part       Pos1    Pos2    Pos3    Pos4
--------------------------------------------------------------
2009            001        8       8       9       7
2009            002        9       7       8       6
2011            001        9       9       8       7
2011            002        7       8       6       8
2013            001        8       9       7       9
2013            002        7       7       8       8
2015            001        10      8       7       4
2015            002        7       6       9       8
```

The `InspectYear`data will always add every 2 years for each Part.
I want to calculate the newest value on each `pos#` column with the previous year (Calc1). Also the newest value with the oldest value (Calc2).

Then, I have the following code:

```
declare @inspectyear as nvarchar(max), @calc as nvarchar(max), @query as nvarchar(max);

set @inspectyear = STUFF((select distinct ',' + quotename(InspectYear) from ##t2 c
                  for XML path(''), type).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

select @calc = ', ' + quotename(Max(InspectYear)) + '  - ' + quotename(Max(InspectYear)-2) 
         + ' as Calc1, ' + quotename(Max(InspectYear)) + ' - ' + quotename(min(InspectYear)) 
         + ' as Calc2' from #t2;

set @query =
';with data as
(
      select      inspectyear,
                  partno, Pos, number
      from #t2
      unpivot
      (
            number
            for Pos in ([Pos1], [Pos2], [Pos3], [Pos4])
      ) unpvt
)
select * ' + @calc + ' into ##temp
from data
pivot
(
      sum(number)
      for inspectyear in (' + @inspectyear + ')
) pvt
order by partno';

exec sp_executesqk @query = @query;
select * from ##temp;
drop table ##temp;
```

the result should be:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Part      Pos      2009    2011    2013    2015    Calc1     Calc2
---------------------------------------------------------------------
001       Pos1     8       9       8       10      2         2
001       Pos2     8       9       9       8       -1        0
001       Pos3     9       8       7       7       0         -2
001       Pos4     7       7       9       4       -5        -3
```

I want to modify the calculation for Calc1 and Calc2 which is:

```
Calc1 = (newest value on each pos# column - value on the previous year on each pos#) / distance from latest year until the previous year.

Calc2 = (newest value on each pos# column - value on the first year on each pos#) / distance from latest year until the first year.
```

For instance:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Part      Pos      2009    2011    2013    2015    Calc1     Calc2
---------------------------------------------------------------------
001       Pos1     8       9       8       10      1         0.333
```

Year distance on the table above are, for `Calc1 2015 - 2013 = 2`
for `Calc2 2015 - 2009 = 6`

So the question is, how can I get the distance between the newest year minus previous year and the newest year minus the oldest year...?

Does anyone have an idea for this?
Thank you.

Comment: The short way of doing this is just changing your @calc thing to be this, I believe: `select @calc = ', (' + quotename(Max(InspectYear)) + '  - ' + quotename(Max(InspectYear)-2) 
         + ') / 2.0 as Calc1, 1.0 * (' + quotename(Max(InspectYear)) + ' - ' + quotename(min(InspectYear)) 
         + ') / (' + cast(max(inspectyear) as char(4)) + '-' + cast(min(inspectyear) as char(4)) + ') as Calc2' from #t2;`

Comment: @ZLK, I didn't get it. Since the Year column is dynamic. So if the new column added. Let say, 2017. then the Calc2 is 2017 minus 2009 = 8. So the divider for Calc2 is 8. Ok for Calc1, It always 2. But I have to show it on the result.

Comment: 2017 - 2009 is 8. that should be max(year) - min(year) which i put in calc2. EDIT: Your `@calc` variable should look like this with your current figures: `, ([2015]  - [2013]) / 2.0 as Calc1, 1.0 * ([2015] - [2009]) / (2015-2009) as Calc2` which would give you the results you expect.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the correction @ZLK, If you don't mind. Could you put it into answer sect.. ? Really appreciated.

Comment: @ZLK, need your help for this link .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521859/get-other-column-to-include-on-pivot-calculation-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the easy fix here is to change the `@calc` variable to look like this:

```
select @calc = ', (' + quotename(Max(InspectYear)) + ' - ' + quotename(Max(InspectYear)-2) 
         + ') / 2.0 as Calc1, 1.0 * (' + quotename(Max(InspectYear)) + ' - ' + quotename(min(InspectYear)) 
         + ') / (' + cast(max(inspectyear) as char(4)) + '-' + cast(min(inspectyear) as char(4)) + ') as Calc2' 
from #t2;
```

Which will give you output similar to this: `, ([2015] - [2013]) / 2.0 as Calc1, 1.0 * ([2015] - [2009]) / (2015-2009) as Calc2`

Answer (score 0):

I put together a version of this but it can definitely be optimized.

To give you an idea of whats happening, run it down to (and including) the commented section. The commented section is then just pivoted to get the result.

```
    CREATE TABLE #t2
              (  InspectYear int 
                ,Part [nchar](5) 
                ,Pos1 int
                ,Pos2 int
                ,Pos3 int
                ,Pos4 int
                )

    Insert Into #t2
    Values
    ('2009','001','8','8','9','7'),
    ('2009','002','9','7','8','6'),
    ('2011','001','9','9','8','7'),
    ('2011','002','7','8','6','8'),
    ('2013','001','8','9','7','9'),
    ('2013','002','7','7','8','8'),
    ('2015','001','10','8','7','4'),
    ('2015','002','7','6','9','8');


    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @count  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @max  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.InspectYear) 
               FROM #t2 c
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
               ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
               ,1,1,'');

    SET @count = (Select COUNT(distinct InspectYear)-1 FROM #t2);
    SET @max = (Select MAX(InspectYear) FROM #t2);

    /* --TESTING & to see how this works
        Select 
            inspectyear,
            part, 
            Pos, 
            number,
            Last_Value(Calc1)Over(Partition by Part,Pos Order by inspectyear ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as Calc1,
            Last_Value(Calc2)Over(Partition by Part,Pos Order by inspectyear ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as Calc2
            from (
                     select 
                            inspectyear,
                            part, 
                            Pos, 
                            number,
                            CASE WHEN inspectyear=@max THEN
                            (number-LAG(number,1,0)Over(Partition by Part,Pos Order by inspectyear))
                            /(inspectyear-LAG(inspectyear,1,0)Over(Partition by Part,Pos Order by inspectyear)) END as Calc1,
                            CASE WHEN inspectyear=@max THEN
                            CAST((number-LAG(number,@count,0)Over(Partition by Part,Pos Order by inspectyear))as decimal(8,7))
                            /(inspectyear-LAG(inspectyear,@count,0)Over(Partition by Part,Pos Order by inspectyear)) END as Calc2
                        from #t2
                        unpivot
                        (
                            number
                            for Pos in ([Pos1], [Pos2], [Pos3], [Pos4])
                            ) unpvt )t3
    Order by  Pos,Part,inspectyear

    */


    set @query = 'SELECT Part,Pos, ' + @cols + ' , Calc1, Calc2 from 
            (
                Select 
            inspectyear,
            part, 
            Pos, 
            number,
            Last_Value(Calc1)Over(Partition by Part,Pos Order by inspectyear ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as Calc1,
            Last_Value(Calc2)Over(Partition by Part,Pos Order by inspectyear ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as Calc2
            from (
                     select 
                            inspectyear,
                            part, 
                            Pos, 
                            number,
                            CASE WHEN inspectyear=' + @max + ' THEN
                            (number-LAG(number,1,0)Over(Partition by Part,Pos Order by inspectyear))
                            /(inspectyear-LAG(inspectyear,1,0)Over(Partition by Part,Pos Order by inspectyear)) END as Calc1,
                            CASE WHEN inspectyear=' + @max + ' THEN
                            CAST((number-LAG(number,' + @count + ',0)Over(Partition by Part,Pos Order by inspectyear))as decimal(8,7))
                            /(inspectyear-LAG(inspectyear,' + @count + ',0)Over(Partition by Part,Pos Order by inspectyear)) END as Calc2
                        from #t2
                        unpivot
                        (
                            number
                            for Pos in ([Pos1], [Pos2], [Pos3], [Pos4])
                            ) unpvt )t3   
    ) x
    pivot 
    (
         SUM(number)
        for inspectyear in (' + @cols + ')
    ) p 

    Order by Part,Pos'
    execute(@query)
```